# Can Googlebot detect duplicate video content?

Tags: duplicate-content, googlebot, video

I downloaded a lot of videos from YouTube and uploaded them to my hosting.

Can Googlebot-video can detect that my video is duplicate?

Comment: Did you really need to do this? Does this make the Internet any better?  All it takes is one manually review and your done.

Comment: Downloading videos of YouTube is against their terms of usage and most videos have reserved rights and with enough DCMA complaints your site will be removed from Google.

Comment: Theoretically speaking, detecting duplicate videos is quite possible and extremely easy to do. I would not be surprised if there was some kind of detection within Google's arsenal even if they have to drag it out of the closet first.

Comment: Why duplicate it? Just embed it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We know that Google has technology to detect duplication within video.   They [use an algorithm at YouTube to detect when any uploaded video uses a copyrighted song](https://www.reddit.com/r/askscience/comments/1rvqha/how_can_youtube_detect_when_copyrighted_music_is/).

While I haven't heard of any specific cases of Google using video duplication detection other than that, it would not surprise me to learn that they do so.   Google would want to detect duplicate video content [the same way that they detect and penalize scraped text content](https://webmasters.stackexchange.com/questions/35652/what-is-duplicate-content-and-how-can-i-avoid-being-penalized-for-it-on-my-site) for ranking purposes.  Google does not publicize most of the algorithms and techniques that they use.

Copying content onto your website without permission is not a good way to build your website.   Google will deindex sites manually for this.   It could also make you vulnerable to legal action from copyright holders.